# flutterの環境構築をしようとしたところ、「flutter not found」となってしまって先に進めない

Tags: flutter

以下のサイトを参考にしてFlutterの環境構築を行い、:wqで上書き保存を行った後に
`which flutter` コマンドを入力後に "flutter not found"と表示され、パスが表示されません。

not found と表示されてしまう原因が分かる方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスお願いします。

[Flutterの環境構築(Mac編)](https://zenn.dev/kboy/books/ca6a9c93fd23f3/viewer/5232dc)

Answer (score 3):

`.zshrc`(もしくは　`.bashrc`)を編集するだけでは駄目で、編集した内容を反映する(読み込む)必要があります。

ターミナルを一旦終了させ起動し直す、というのが簡単でわかりやすい反映方法かと考えます。

Answer (score 1):

まずはFlutter公式サイトを見た方がいいと思います。

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos/mobile-android#install-the-flutter-sdk

ここではVSCodeで簡単にFlutterをインストールする方法が書かれています。

Flutter自体はただのフォルダです、その中のbinの実行可能なファイルでflutterコマンドを実行しているだけです。

もしどうしても"flutter not found"が表示し続けるでしたらbinのフルパスをflutterの代わりに使っても全然問題ないです。（ただコマンドが長くなるだけです、他の支障はありません）

例えば私の場合は：

```
/Users/user/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter doctor
```

遅くなって回答していますが、他の人の助けにもなればと思って書かせていただきます。